# Making .value value 0 instead of null in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
var drikke = 
parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="drikke"]:checked').value);
if (typeof drikke == null) {

    drikke == 0;

}
```

How do I make the `.value` return `0` instead of `null`, which is ruining my program?

Comment: Could you please poste you html part of the code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first get the element with:

```
var drikke = document.querySelector('input[name="drikke"]');
```

Then check if it is `checked` get its numeric value with the use of [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) and if not, make it 0 with the use of logical operators [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```
drikke = drikke.checked && +drikke.value || 0;
```

Code example:

```js
function regnut() {
  var drikke = document.querySelector('input[name="drikke"]');
  var mat = document.querySelector('input[name="mat"]');  
  var tilbehør = document.querySelector('input[name="tilbehør"]');  
  var dip = document.querySelector('input[name="dip"]'); 

  drikke = drikke.checked && +drikke.value || 0;
  mat = mat.checked && +mat.value || 0;
  tilbehør = tilbehør.checked && +tilbehør.value || 0;
  dip = dip.checked && +dip.value || 0;

  totalpris = drikke + mat + tilbehør + dip;
  document.querySelector('#output').value = drikke + mat + tilbehør + dip;
  console.log(drikke + mat + tilbehør + dip);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter-ui.css');
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);
  font-family: 'Inter UI', sans-serif;
}

#drikke,
#mat,
#tilbehør,
#dip {
  float: left;
}

#resultat {
  display: inline;
}

input {
  margin: 4px;
}

#fresh {
  font-family: 'Inter UI', sans-serif;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Velkommen til Mc-bergbys</h1><br>
<h3>Velkommen til menyvelgeren</h3><br>
<h4>Sett sammen din meny under</h4><br>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Navn??"><br>
<div id="drikke">
  <input type="radio" name="drikke" value="25" id="cola">Cola<br>
  <input type="radio" name="drikke" value="25" id="solo">Solo<br>
  <input type="radio" name="drikke" value="25" id="sitron">Sitronbrus<br>
  <input type="radio" name="drikke" value="0" id="vann">Vann<br>
</div>
<div id="mat">
  <input type="radio" name="mat" value="30" id="hamburger">Hamburger<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mat" value="40" id="kylling">Kylling<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mat" value="40" id="cheeseburger">Cheeseburger<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mat" value="30" id="nuggets">Nuggets<br>
</div>
<div id="tilbehør">
  <input type="radio" name="tilbehør" value="15" id="pommes">Pommes Frites<br>
  <input type="radio" name="tilbehør" value="20" id="løkringer">Løkringer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="tilbehør" value="20" id="cheesesticks">Cheesesticks<br>
  <br>
</div>
<div id="dip">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dip" value="5" id="ketchup">Ketchup<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="dip" value="5" id="sennep">Sennep<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="dip" value="5" id="grillkrydder">Grillkrydder<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="dip" value="5" id="dip">Dip<br>
</div>
<div id="resultat">
  <br><br>
  <button id="sendinn" onclick="regnut()">Regn ut</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="totalpris" readonly="true" id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`||` logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()):

```
var drikke = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="drikke"]:checked').value) || 0;
```

#### [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z37a9mcq/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8tr2zumk/#&togetherjs=QxK7eEKKkV this is my code if you want to look at the entirety of it.

Comment: @Ken just updated the fiddle. You can take a look at it. I think the issue was it wasn't able to find the function in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your code following way:

```
var drikkeElm = document.querySelector('input[name="drikke"]:checked');
var drikke = -1;
if(drikkeElm === null){
    drikke = 0;
}else{
    drikke = parseInt(drikkeElm.value);
}

alert(drikke);
```